# When is a broadcast overkill?

Tags: apache-spark

I have started working on a Scala Spark codebase where everything that can be broadcasted seems to be, even small objects (a handful of small String attributes)

For example, I see this a lot:

```
val csvParser: CSVParser = new CSVParser(someComputedValue())
val csvParserBc = sc.broadcast(csvParser)
someFunction(..., csvParserBc)
```

My question is twofold:

- Is broadcasting useful when a small object is reused in several closures?
- Is broadcasting useful when a small object is used one single time?

I'm under the impression that in that cases broadcasting is not useful, and could even be wasteful, but I'd like a more enlightened opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you broadcast something it is copied to each executor once. If you don't broadcast it, it's copied along with each task. So broadcasting is useful if you have a large object and/or many more tasks than executors.

In my experience this is very rarely the case. Broadcast complicates the code. So I would always start off without a broadcast and only add a broadcast if I find that this is required for good performance.

Comment: Sorry for the opinion-based answer. I hope someone can give you a more objective answer!

Comment: Since there isn't really a lot of information about Broadcasts available, I would agree to this.